# Java template project for Automation Testing for a new WebApp? In any framework

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, webdriver

Can anybody suggest me any preset template project for a new web application?

Using Java and Selenium Webdriver I’m looking for a skeleton project with preset pages and basic methods for automation. For pages like LoginPage, BasePage etc. With list of web elements, which will be corrected and specified of course.

Framework could be like Gauge, Sahi, TestNG or something similiar.

What I need is a template project, to not start from absolute scratch. Thank you for any help.

Comment: _"Can anybody suggest me any preset template "_ -- this type of question is explicitly off-topic here. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ExampIes section I found nothing wrong about the way I asked the question.

Comment: Read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and specifically the point number four. Take some time to read also the other sections, very helpful specially to learn how to make a good (and on-topic) question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have **maven** installed in your machine. Then you have to just run two commands to get the skeleton project in a given directory.

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

Enter project template code : **978** (testNG based)

Input groupId , artefactId, version and packaging type. After few seconds, you shall get a template project in your directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’m actually using maven to run test suites. While creating a new maven project, where can I enter this project template code (like 987) to generate a testNG project ?

Comment: on command prompt , after running mvn archetype:generate. A prompt will appear with a list of template projects. There you go.

Answer (score 0):

I am often in the situation where I ask myself "how do I rapidly prototype a java & maven web app with login and basic authentication?"

Using Java and Spring Boot, you can follow one of the tutorials on Spring website, such as: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/. It's a partial response to a question that is a little bit too broad.